# Page event jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile

I need the event that called a function every time the page is access.Let's say enter to page1 -> call the function ,after that enter to page 2 and when user return to page 1 again call that function.
I try with 'pageinit' but this event will call just first time.Can anyone help me?

The structure `<div role="page" id="page1>,<div role="page" id="page2>`

Answer (score 0):

See jquery mobile documentation about events (http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/). You can find which events are thrown in which order depending on the case in this site, but it is not fully up-to-date as some event are deprecated and will be removed in future versions: http://www.gajotres.net/page-events-order-in-jquery-mobile/

You should use pagecontainershow event (http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-show) like this:

```
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
   alert( "This page was shown: " + ui.toPage);
});
```

But I think your html structure is not correct: if you are using JQM, you should have `data-role="page"` instead of `role="page"`. The error may also be there